# Android setting and getting radio button values as instance variables

Tags: android, radio-button, instance

Pulling my hair out here. No matter what radio button is selected the package price always comes out to 525.00. Any idea's as to what I am doing wrong?

```
            //Get and set package selected.
            radioPackageGroup = (RadioGroup)   findViewById(R.id.radTadPackage);
            int selectedId = radioPackageGroup.getCheckedRadioButtonId();
            btnPackage = (RadioButton) findViewById(selectedId);
            String display_package_selected = btnPackage.getText().toString(); 
            TadGlobals.getTadPackageInstance().setTadPackage(display_package_selected);     

            //Set package price.
            double package_price = 0.00;
            if(display_package_selected == "Bronze"){
                package_price = 150.00;
            }else if(display_package_selected == "Silver"){
                package_price = 225.00;
            }else if(display_package_selected == "Gold"){
                package_price = 375.00;
            }else{
                package_price = 525.00;
            }
            TadGlobals.getPackagePriceInstance().setPackagePrice(package_price);
```

Comment: Oh, I forgot to add. I tested the instance variable that holds the string value of the radio button that was selected...so if user chose "Bronze" the string "Bronze" is getting returned.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use String.equals() method to compare string objects:

```
if(display_package_selected.equals("Bronze")) 
{
                package_price = 150.00;
}
else if(display_package_selected.equals("Silver"))
{
                package_price = 225.00;
}
else if(display_package_selected.equals("Gold"))
{
                package_price = 375.00;
}
else
{
                package_price = 525.00;
}
```